# I am having a problem with in infinite loop in my python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python and having a problem with an infinite loop in my program. It produces my print statements correctly but continues infinitely. My else statement at the end also does not work for some reason.

```
day = "Lets see how many classes you will have today."
day += "\nInput 'Finished' when you are done. What day is today? "
day = input(day)
active = True
while True:

    if day == 'Finished':
        active = False
    elif day == 'Wednesday':
        print("You should have just 1 class today!")


    elif day == 'Thursday':
        print("You should have 4 classes today!")


    elif day == 'Friday':
        print("You should have 2 classes today! ")


    elif day == 'Saturday':
        print("You should have 4 classes today! ")


    elif day == 'Sunday':
        print("You should have 4 classes today!")


    elif day =='Monday' or 'Tuesday':
        print("You don't have any classes today. Sit back and relax!")

    else:
        print("That is not a valid day dumbass!")
```

Comment: ...or `while active:` and want to bring `day = input(day)` inside loop.

Comment: In your own words, what are you *expecting* to cause the loop to exit?

Comment: The last `elif` in your code should be `elif day == 'Monday' or day == 'Tuesday'`

Comment: @KevinFloyd If you found an answer that fixed your problem, mark it as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than `while True`, you should loop `while active`

Additionally, your final `elif` condition should be

```
elif day == 'Monday' or day == 'Tuesday':
```

You also need to accept input in the loop as per @dspencer's comment

Complete solution is

```
day = "Lets see how many classes you will have today."
day += "\nInput 'Finished' when you are done. What day is today? "

active = True
while active:
    day = input(day)

    if day == 'Finished':
        active = False
    elif day == 'Wednesday':
        print("You should have just 1 class today!")


    elif day == 'Thursday':
        print("You should have 4 classes today!")


    elif day == 'Friday':
        print("You should have 2 classes today! ")


    elif day == 'Saturday':
        print("You should have 4 classes today! ")


    elif day == 'Sunday':
        print("You should have 4 classes today!")


    elif day =='Monday' or day == 'Tuesday':
        print("You don't have any classes today. Sit back and relax!")

    else:
        print("That is not a valid day dumbass!")
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using while True use

```
active = True
while active:
```

Also, code the following inside the loop so that you accept the day again and again until day == 'Finished' is encountered.

```
day = input(day)
```

otherwise, it will never come out of the while loop and enter into infinite loop

Another solution is to break when active is false break the loop using break keyword

```
if day == 'Finished':
        active = False
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit too much complexity introduced in this code. You should look up using a dictionary switch in Python.

There are many ways to do what you'd like, but here are the issues with your approach and how to fix them:

Your code almost works, but it has 4 problems.

1: You did not indent your `while` loop

2: You didn't give your program a way to `break` the loop.

3: The `or` statement in the last elif should be written differently.

4: You need to request a different day in each if/elif/else loop/

Here is the corrected code:

```
day = "Lets see how many classes you will have today."
day += "\nInput 'Finished' when you are done. What day is today? "
day = input(day)
active = True
while active: #This was changed

    if day == 'Finished':
         active = False #This was changed

    elif day == 'Wednesday':
        print("You should have just 1 class today!")
        day = input("enter day: ") #This was added everywhere

    elif day == 'Thursday':
        print("You should have 4 classes today!")
        day = input("enter day: ")

    elif day == 'Friday':
        print("You should have 2 classes today! ")
        day = input("enter day: ")

    elif day == 'Saturday':
        print("You should have 4 classes today! ")
        day = input("enter day: ")

    elif day == 'Sunday':
        print("You should have 4 classes today!")
        day = input("enter day: ")

    elif day =='Monday' or day == 'Tuesday': #This was changed remember that ambiguity is your enemy!
        print("You don't have any classes today. Sit back and relax!")
        day = input("enter day: ")
    else:
        print("That is not a valid day!")
        day = input("enter day: ")
```